Converting a linear equation into a Bernoulli equation
If we have a Bernoulli differential equation we can covert it to a linear one though a substitution. Is it possible to go the other way around, that is, can any linear 1st order differential equation be converted into a Bernoulli differential equation?

Yes. The general form of the Bernoulli differential equation can be written as $$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = f(x) y + g(x) y^a  $$
where $a \ne 1$, which the transformation $$y = u^{1/(1-a)} $$
transforms to
$$ \dfrac{du}{dx} = (1-a) (f(x) u + g(x)) $$
The general form of the first-order linear differential equation is
$$ \dfrac{du}{dx} = F(x) u + G(x) $$
so you can choose any $a \ne 1$ and use the inverse transformation
$$ u = y^{1-a} $$
to make this into a Bernoulli differential equation with $f(x) = F(x)/(1-a)$ and $g(x) = G(x)/(1-a)$.
